# How to add DataGridView dynamically to TabPage

Tags: c#, windows, datagridview, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have a TabControl.
I dynamically want to add TabPages that would have dynamically added DataGridView.
I am able to add the tabPages dynamically but when I add the DataGridView to the dynamic tabPage nothing shows up.
Appreciate any help that can be provided.

Here is the code.

```
                    myTabPage.SuspendLayout();
                    tabControlNonQueued.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);
                    loadDataGridToTab(dataTable, myTabPage);
    private void loadDataGridToTab(DataTable dt, TabPage tab)
    {
        DataGridView grid = new DataGridView();
        tab.Controls.Add(grid);
        tab.Refresh();
        grid.Visible = true;
        System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
        grid.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        grid.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        grid.AutoSizeColumnsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        grid.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle;
        grid.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        dataGridViewCellStyle.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        dataGridViewCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
        dataGridViewCellStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        dataGridViewCellStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.WindowText;
        dataGridViewCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight;
        dataGridViewCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HighlightText;
        dataGridViewCellStyle.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
        grid.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle;
        grid.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        //grid.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
        //this.cbDG});


        hideDGColumn(grid, "Counter");
        SetFontAndColors(grid);
        lockDataGrid(grid);
        BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
        source.DataSource = dt;
        grid.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        grid.DataSource = source;

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084098/creating-a-tab-control-with-a-dynamic-number-of-tabs-in-visual-studio-c-sharp - This might help.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried moving the tab.Controls.Add(grid) statement to after the grid is configured?

Separately, I notice you are using "SuspendLayout()" to allow flicker free updates.  Are you remembering to turn layout back on again?

For example, this:

```
myTabPage.SuspendLayout();
tabControlNonQueued.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);
DataGridView grid = new DataGridView();

// ... grid configuration and setup here ...

tab.Controls.Add(grid);
myTabPage.ResumeLayout();
tab.Refresh();
```

Comment: I did all the changes you suggested. I added ResumeLayout and also refresh and moved the DataGridView adding to the very end. It did not help. The dataGridView does not show up on the dynamically added tabPages. Thanks

Comment: Just to verify, I added a checkBox control and that gets added and show up correct.           private void loadDataGridToTab(DataTable dt, TabPage tab,string tabName)
        {
            DataGridView grid = new DataGridView();
            System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox cbSelectAll = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
            tab.Controls.Add(cbSelectAll);
            tab.Controls.Add(grid);

Comment: Is it possible you're adding the DataGridView to the wrong parent?  For example, a tab control consists of a number of things: (1) the tab control itself, (2) the pages, (3) the child elements in the pages.  I notice that this code just uses the variable "tab" - is it possible that's not the correct element?

Comment: Also, try reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678184/c-sharp-winforms-tabcontrol-elements-reading-as-empty-until-tabpage-selected?rq=1 - you may not be able to add the element until the tab page is shown.  You may need to move your code into the "TabPageSelected" event.

Comment: I had to set it to visible. Even though I set it visible before adding to the tab. I have it set it visible once added to tab as well now GridView show.              tab.Refresh();        grid.Visible = true;
 Thanks Ted.

Comment: For tabs, "Visible" is different from "shown".  For example, all five tab pages may be "visible", but only one at a time is "shown".